# Why am I receiving a TweepError('Authentication required!')?

Tags: python, api, tweepy

I'm trying to create a Twitter bot with Tweepy that will search through the tweets on my timeline, and find tweets matching a particular keyword ("brexit"), and retweet those tweets. My developer account is the same account that I would like to do the retweeting.

I have followed everything, I believe, to the book. This is my code:

```py
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import time

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("XXX", "XXX")
auth.set_access_token("XXX", "XXX")
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class listener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print("Tweet arrived!")
        print("Authors name: %s" % status.author.screen_name)
        status.retweet()
        time.sleep(10)

    def on_error(selfself, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            return False

keywords = ["brexit"]

def search_tweets():
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    tweetlistener = listener()
    stream = tweepy.Stream(tweepy.api.home_timeline(), listener = tweetlistener)
    stream.filter(track=keywords)

search_tweets()
```

However, I am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/borde/Documents/PythonProjects/brexitbot/botcode.py", line 29, in <module>
    search_tweets()
  File "C:/Users/borde/Documents/PythonProjects/brexitbot/botcode.py", line 26, in search_tweets
    stream = tweepy.Stream(tweepy.api.home_timeline(), listener = tweetlistener)
  File "C:\Users\borde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 245, in _call
    method = APIMethod(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\borde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 44, in __init__
    raise TweepError('Authentication required!')
tweepy.error.TweepError: Authentication required!
```

I've tried resetting the keys, to make sure that they hadn't been timed out, but it still isn't working. I also tried changing the listener class so that it just prints out the found tweets, as opposed to retweeting them.

I'm completely new to this, and any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do those XXXs represent the following secrets in order: `consumer_key`, `consumer_secret`, `access_token` and `access_token_secret`?

Comment: @ipaleka yes they do

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html#step-1-creating-a-streamlistener), you'll see that the first argument to that `Stream` call should be your instantiated api object's auth attribute:

```
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
```

You just instantiated your api TWICE and not using it at all. Delete that duplicate line from `search_tweets` and instantiate stream like this:

```
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener = tweetlistener)
```

P.S. you're passing an instance instead of class, c/p the following instead of your function:

```
def search_tweets():
    stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=listener)
    stream.filter(track=keywords)
```

Btw, you should name your classes starting with uppercase letter, change `class listener(tweepy.StreamListener):` to `class Listener(tweepy.StreamListener):` and in that code I just provided: `listener=Listener`.

Comment: I just tried this, but still received the same error message.